# How to switch all the modules in a project from debug to release in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I opened [some project](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan) containing multiple modules in Android Studio and build multiple debug APKs.

But switching from debug to release become a bit problematic for me.

Is there a way to switch all the modules with one button or should I select `release` one by one?

See the screenshot of my `Build Variants` window:

[image]

**EDIT1:**

Tried to run `switchToRelease` task from the answer, but got the following error:

```
Build file 'D:\dev\repos\Vulkan\android\build.gradle' line: 24

Execution failed for task ':switchToRelease'.
> No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.StartParameterInternal.getEnabledProjects() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```